# Find the sum of the coefficients in front of the even degrees of x in the normal form of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Find the sum of the coefficients in front of the even degrees of x in the normal form of a polynomial
>   $$(x^6 + x + 1)^{2015} + (x^6 + x - 1)^{2015}$$

I am familiar with the binomial theorem , as well as implications for odd and even degrees , but just do not know how to apply it in this case.

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: To find  sum of even power of the coefficient

Comment: Flagged to close your question. Please edit your question and make clear what you are asking or your question will be closed.

Comment: Sorry about this, just need a simple solution.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to begin with! How can someone provide a solution to such a question?!

Comment: Very sorry, is it ok ?

Comment: Please check to make sure that the question is properly stated.  It was difficult to read before.  Also, please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advise.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: It`s not homework, but thanks for atention.

Comment: If you're asking what the title implies you're asking, the sum of coefficients of even powers of $x$ is given by $\dfrac{f(-1)+f(1)}{2}$.

Comment: For numbers $A$ and $B$ it is generally false that $A^{2015}+B^{2015}=(A+B)^{2015}$. Be careful in your manipulations.

Comment: Ok, thanks, any ideas ?

Comment: pjs36 What do you mean by that ?

Comment: Solve the problem , I realized that we should seek those monomials that are of type x^6к, their sum gives us seek, 2^2015 ! Thank however, please advice how to express myself to be most easily understood. Greetings :)